# Rails Controller: How to return list of specific objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to set my @users variable to a specific list of users (whose id's are specified in a file).

This is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
unloadable
require 'will_paginate/array'

ENTRIES_PER_PAGE = 15

def index
    if some_condition
      @users = User.all
    ...
    ...
    ...

    /* inside else block */
    ids = []
    File.open("./user_ids.txt", "r") do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
        ids.push[line]
      end
    end

    /* ??? */
#   @users = User.find(ids)
    /* When above line is uncommented, application throws error */
```

The commented line throws an error, I think because @users isn't an array, but something else, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_entries' for #<Array:0x000000044aa688>)
```

[total_entries](https://makandracards.com/makandra/858-retrieve-the-total-number-of-records-when-paginating-with-will_paginate) is defined from the [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

```
<p> Total entries: <%= @users.total_entries %> </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because when you do `User.find(ids)` it will return an array, just do `User.where(id: ids).paginate(page: params[:page])`

Comment: Almost worked! But it said: "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `total_entries' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000332f458>):
"